# 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list', using dbFD(). FD package

Tags: r, vector, data-analysis

I am trying to run

```
dbFD(traits, as.matrix(abun))
```

but i receive this error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

my data looks similar, but larger to this:

```
      <traits>                           <abun>
      t1     t2     t3  ...             sp1  sp2  sp3  sp4....
sp1   <NA>   0.2    10            A     0.2   0   0.3   0
sp2   100.1  0.3    8.9           B     0.1  0.2   0   0.3 
sp3   80.9   <NA>  11.2           C      0    0   0.1  0.6
sp4   79.2   0.1   <NA>           D      0    0   0.2  0.3
...

typeof(traits)
> "list"
typeof(as.matrix(abun))
> "double"
class(traits)
>"data.frame"
class(as.matrix(abun))
>"matrix"
```

I had checked another similar questions with this error but the answers are similar to:

```
unlist(as.matrix(abund)) ####these way all the columns join into one row, 
                         ####so i can't use dbFD function
```

Any help would be very appreciated!